# Import Payment Voucher for a Particular Bill (Against Ref) through XML Request in Tally

Tags: xml, erp, tally

I am trying to import a payment voucher for a particular bill through XML request in Tally. I was partially successful in doing it.

I was only able to import a payment voucher against an Account but not Against a Reference (Particular bill).

Here is the XML Request:

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>Import</TALLYREQUEST>
<TYPE>Data</TYPE>
<ID>Vouchers</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Test Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</DESC>
<DATA>
<TALLYMESSAGE>
<VOUCHER>
<DATE>20190302</DATE>
<NARRATION>Test Import Payment</NARRATION>
<VOUCHERTYPENAME>Payment</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
<ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<LEDGERNAME>Test Bill</LEDGERNAME>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<AMOUNT>-2.00</AMOUNT>
</ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<LEDGERNAME>Cash</LEDGERNAME>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<AMOUNT>2.00</AMOUNT>
</ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
</VOUCHER>
</TALLYMESSAGE>
</DATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

The above XML successfully creates a Payment voucher On Account but not against a Reference.

I have made some XML changes (adding **BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST** tag) to achieve my desired result but it ends up giving the same result.

```
<ENVELOPE>
<HEADER>
<VERSION>1</VERSION>
<TALLYREQUEST>Import</TALLYREQUEST>
<TYPE>Data</TYPE>
<ID>Vouchers</ID>
</HEADER>
<BODY>
<DESC>
<STATICVARIABLES>
<SVCURRENTCOMPANY>Test Company</SVCURRENTCOMPANY>
</STATICVARIABLES>
</DESC>
<DATA>
<TALLYMESSAGE>
<VOUCHER>
<DATE>20190302</DATE>
<NARRATION>Test Import Payment</NARRATION>
<VOUCHERTYPENAME>Payment</VOUCHERTYPENAME>
<ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<LEDGERNAME>Test Bill</LEDGERNAME>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>Yes</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<AMOUNT>-2.00</AMOUNT>
<BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
<NAME>777</NAME>
<BILLTYPE>Agst Ref</BILLTYPE>
<TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>No</TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>
<AMOUNT>-₹ 2.00</AMOUNT>
<INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST> </INTERESTCOLLECTION.LIST>
<STBILLCATEGORIES.LIST> </STBILLCATEGORIES.LIST>
</BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
</ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
<LEDGERNAME>Cash</LEDGERNAME>
<ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>No</ISDEEMEDPOSITIVE>
<AMOUNT>2.00</AMOUNT>
</ALLLEDGERENTRIES.LIST>
</VOUCHER>
</TALLYMESSAGE>
</DATA>
</BODY>
</ENVELOPE>
```

Kindly help me in achieving my desired output. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 3):

I have removed the rupee symbol from the Amount Tag inside BillAllocations.List

```
<BILLALLOCATIONS.LIST>
<NAME>777</NAME>
<BILLTYPE>Agst Ref</BILLTYPE>
<TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>No</TDSDEDUCTEEISSPECIALRATE>
<AMOUNT>-2.00</AMOUNT>
```

After this, I am able to import payment voucher against a particular Bill.